# Can you say "hasta la hora" when you leave?

Tags: expresiones

I have heard the expression several times here in Barcelona. I am not entirely sure whether they say "hasta la hora" or "hasta ahorra". What of the two is it and can you generally use it to say goodbye?

Comment: ahora=now, ahorra=he or she saves [money]

Answer (score 0):

**"Hasta la hora" o "Hasta ahorra".**

Ninguna de las dos

> Neither of the two

La expresión es "**Hasta ahora**"

> The expression is "**Hasta ahora**"

---

**Hasta ahora**

*Expresión que se utiliza para despedirse de alguien a quien se espera volver a ver en un plazo muy breve de tiempo.*

**Hasta ahora**

> Expression used to say goodbye to someone who is expected to see again
> in a very short period of time.

Comment: Diego, say goodbye to someone you expect to see again. I don't understand why you insist on bilingual answers. Is it worth it to make every one bilingual? The English is: See you later. That is worth saying.

Comment: @lambie, espero que tu fin de semana haya sido grato, en español es indistinto decir ¡hasta ahora!, ¡hasta la vista!, ¡hasta pronto! o ¡hasta luego!,  aunque muchas veces es el contexto de la despedida y el sentimiento de alejarse hasta ese otro momento de encuentro el que impone que locución elegir, se espera que el tiempo no sea muy lejano, ¡hasta que nos veamos la próxima vez!. Esa próxima vez  puede hacer referencia simplemente, a dentro de un instante, hasta que nos veamos de nuevo, nos crucemos por la calle, nos llamemos por teléfono... engloba más cosas que el simple I'll see you later!

Comment: Sé todo eso. Porque me haces un curso? :) Hasta ahora es I'll see (talk, call) you later.

Comment: El temor de molestar a vuecelencia no me permite descender a las observaciones particulares que pudieran hacerse sobre estos menesteres, sin embargo en su empeño, el más importante y que resume a todos ellos y que antes el olvido me jugo, es el ¡Nos vemos!, locución sin par de la cual, por supuesto, también será buen conocedor tanto de ella como de otras tantas. Sin embargo del "adiós", voz más distante, sabrá por igual sus distintas variantes y como precede a las hasta ahora conocidas. No me atrevería por Dios en advertir o comentarlas con VM.  ¡Tenga la dicha en paz!  :)

Answer (score 0):

In Spanish, the only one right is **hasta ahora**.

Throughout Catalonia, when they speak Spanish, they tend to mix Catalan idioms adapted to Spanish, which in most cases are incorrect, although commonly used, especially among people who find themselves in the situation of speaking Spanish when their usual language is Catalan.

### Fins aleshores

[image]

An erroneous translation in Spanish due to the similarity of the words of *"fins aleshores"* is *"hasta las horas"*, where, although the meaning seems to be the same, in Spanish it's incorrect. **Hasta la hora** seems to be a misused Catalanism in Spanish.

Comment: Hasta la vista, baby. :)